# Understanding what patching mean when installing programs

Tags: software, macos

I've downloaded a program which gives me the instructions in this order:

> <sub>[MacOSX]
>
>   1.Install/Update the software.
>
>   2.Copy patched AU/VST/RTAS.
>
>   3.Run our keygen on Windows.
>
>   4.Run the software and start activation.
>
>   5.Select offline activation.
>
>   6.Copy ComputerID to the keygen.
>
>   7.Generate a Serial Number and an Authorization File.
>
>   8.Register and Enjoy!</sub>

I opened Wine on my macbook in order to get the keygen to work.  However, when I save the authorization file it does not appear on my desktop.

Although, my main problem here is understanding what patching actually means.
What is it asking me to do?
I don't understand what I must do in order to activate this program.

Comment: You definitely should not be requesting help regarding software cracks/keygens.

Comment: I'm not convinced that Gason realized s/he was attempting to install a pirated app. This might have been a good opportunity to explain what patching is and why it's a threat to the security of one's computer, data and general privacy.

Comment: @Zero I second Gason's suggestion. This seems like a perfect opportunity for that kind of explanation. I'd write such an answer myself right now if I weren't knackered.

Comment: Could I ask @zero to perhaps edit the question for formatting and grammar

Comment: I've tweaked this for format - someone else may have to make the decision on content. My answer only answers 'what is a patch?' & nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

A Patch is a small executable file which is used to change usually small sections of an existing application's code - for instance to fix small bugs noticed after the app's release… or, unfortunately in this case, to bypass the app's built-in security.

In this instance, with the patch being unofficial & not distributed by the original developers, you have no way of knowing what additional payload might be in the patch - including key loggers, phone home code, botnet distribution networks… etc, etc.

Patches are not as common as they used to be.
Their benefit of being small & lightweight was most useful back when we were all on slow dial-up connections & software was released on CD/DVD - making it a large task to update user's software by sending out new CDs or making them download entire new versions.
A patch of only a few MB was then the best way to update.

Now we all have faster connections, the trend is now to issue a brand new updated version, which overwrites the old version entirely.